# How to search for objects in the Django User model

Tags: django, search, django-users

I have a Profile model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ...
```

And a search contacts view:

```
class SearchContactsView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/contact_search.html'
    context_object_name = 'qs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        q1 = self.request.GET.get('contact_name')
        q2 = self.request.GET.get('contact_location')

        if q1 or q2:
            return Profile.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=q1) |
                                          Q(last_name__icontains=q1),
                                          location__icontains=q2)

        return Profile.objects.all()
```

It is working fine but I would like to be able to search for contacts via the user field as well. Does anyone know a way to do that?

**EDIT** my user's username's are created by them when they sign up to the site and are currently uneditable. They are displayed on the admin page via a dropdown since they are a OneToOneField. I think my issue is that django recognises them only as an IntegerField('pk') but I need to somehow cast them as a string value. Am I right in thinking that, and if so how can this be achieved?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your template to allow user to input user_username and save that username to q3:

```
q3 = self.request.GET.get('user_username')
```

After that you can adjust your If condition accordingly, then change your return to something like:

```
Profile.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=q1) |
                                          Q(last_name__icontains=q1),
                                          location__icontains=q2,
                                          user__username=q3)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your method, but I do not have the option to search by `user_username` only `user`, but every time I search by `user` django expects a number as an `id`.

Comment: @sgt_pepper85 then can you post whatever you have already tried?

Comment: I have tried a few variations of `user__icontains=q3`, `user_username=q3`, `user.username=q3`. Nothing works as I'd like because I am either searching by a field that doesn't exist, or because Django is looking for an 'id' while I am hoping to return a string. I have edited my original post, hopefully what i am trying to achieve makes a little more sense now

Comment: @sgt_pepper85 I don't know what your self.request.GET returns. Adjust `q3 = self.request.GET.get('user_username')` according to what your self.request.GET return. I told you to add something to your template to allow that q3.

Comment: I tried your method again, after realising I'd been a fool and added an extra space at the end of `('user_username ')`. What it is returning is `Profile.objects.all()` regardless of what values I input.